# filter select field using previous field in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a model Company that belongs to an Industry.

When an affiliate signs up, I want to filter the name of the companies by industry. So when the user selects the industry, the next field shows only the name of the companies that belong to that Industry.

On the form I have this:

```
<%= f.collection_select( Industry.all, :id, :name) %>
<%= f.collection_select(:industry_id, Company.all, :id, :name) %>
```

It gives me a select for all the industries and for companies, but how can I filter the name of the companies to change when the industry is selected?

Comment: what did you try?

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to do it with ajax. i can show you path

1- On change Industry's name you need to send a ajax call to controller.
ex -

```
  $('#industry_select_box_id').on('change', function(){
    var industry_id = $('#industry_select_box_id :selected').val();
    $.ajax({
      url: "/get_company_lists_url",
      type: "GET",
      data : {
        id: industry_id
      },
      dataType: "script",
    });
  })
```

2- Make an action (ex- company_lists) to your controller to get companies lists from this ajax call. and replace `/get_company_lists_url` with this acrion's url in ajax call. and get `@comapany_lists` with your `params[industry_id]`

3- make a partial of like `_companies_lists.html.erb`
 and make a select_tag with the same name that name you using in `f.collection_select(:industry_id, Company.all, :id, :name)` you can get name by inspect element in broswer. and in partial(suppose your next slect box name is like - comapny[industry_id])

```
<%= select_tag "comapny[industry_id]", options_from_collection_for_select(@comapany_lists, :id, :name) %>
```

note- here your `@comapany_lists` is the variable that you getting from ajax call

4- in js.erb (ex- company_lists.erb)

```
$('#your_company_lists_div_id').html("j render 'companies_lists'");
```

note here `your_company_lists_div_id` is the id of div where you want to show your selected comapny lists related with industry

summary-  simply ajax call with on change your industry and render a partial with selected company lists.
hope this should work for you, thank you, you can ask in comment in case of any concern.

Comment: Sorry, dude. I have been trying to understand everything you said for days but I am still confused on most of it. Could you explain 3 a little better?

Comment: Have you ever tried to call ajax request on `on change` event  of selectbox, its as simple that, what i'm explaining here that you have to just send a id of industry on change of selectbox via ajax and render a company list associated with that industry in another selectbox. thats it. just try it